# MS Access VBA reference for Outlook not working since recent Office update

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access db using VBA to create calendar events in Outlook. It had been working up until this week. An update to Office was pushed out at the beginning of this week, so it seems to be where my problem is.

When I try to run the event I get an error that says, "Object library not supported." In the Access references, I have MS Outlook 16.0 Object Library and OLE Automation, as well as MS Access 16.0 Object Library, MS Office 16.0 Access db engine Object Library, and MS ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.

What reference do I need to add to make Access VBA work with Outlook again? TIA

Comment: You should always deploy applications using late binding (i.e. no reference set to non-basic object libraries) in order to stop issues like this arising. You need to replace `Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application` with `Dim objOutlook As Object:Set objOutlook=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and also replace any constants with either their numeric value or else declare a global constant with that value.

Comment: @Applecore That completely defeats the point of statically-typed programming though... Also, plenty of COM interfaces cannot be used in late-bound contexts: if I remember correctly (COM-related PTSD notwithstanding...) only COM interfaces extending `IDispatch` can be used in late-bound contexts.

Comment: @Dai - 90% of the time, folk are automating Office applications (Excel/Word/Outlook) from Access, and it is "safer" to use late binding in these cases, as you cannot control the version of these applications used on target machines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested solution without success. It was a database issue and I fixed it by running a decompile script in windows command prompt. Below is the code I used. You must include quotations marks at the very beginning and very end.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" /decompile "L:\[folder]\[subfolder]\[accessdbname].accdb"
```